# Populate 3 times in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I already have nested populate working with putting Company into the User and then Store into the Company.

```
User.find().sort('-created').populate({
    path: 'company2'
}).exec(function (err, docs) {
    User.populate(docs, {
            path: 'company2.store',
            model: 'Store'
        },
        function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.render('error', {
                    status: 500
                });
            } else {
                res.jsonp(data);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Now I'm trying to populate a third time by putting Section into the Store. How do I add another populate in there?

path should be company2.store.section

model should be 'Section'

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it (I think)

```
User.find().sort('-created').populate({
    path: 'company2'
}).exec(function (err, docs) {

    User.populate(docs, {
            path: 'company2.store',
            model: 'Store'

        },
        function (err, data) {
            console.log("User List data: %j", data);


            if (err) {
                res.render('error', {
                    status: 500
                });
            } else {
                User.populate(docs, {
                        path: 'company2.store.section',
                        model: 'Section'

                    },
                    function (err, data2) {



                        if (err) {
                            res.render('error', {
                                status: 500
                            });
                        } else {
                            res.jsonp(data2);
                        }

                    }


                );




            }

        }


    );



});
```